# Difference of text and polygon results in hole that is smaller than original text

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to make a single path by taking the difference between a polygon and a text letter, but when I perform the `Path > Difference` the hole that is made in the polygon is much smaller than the original letter.

I have tried converting the text to a path using `Stroke to Path` and `Object to Path` to no avail. I also tried creating an intersection of the text and polygon, but the resulting letter-path was larger than the original letter.

How can I punch a hole in this polygon using the outline of a letter?

Here's a picture of the result I'm getting now:

[image]

Comment: Compound Path (Ctrl+K / Cmd+K)

Comment: @Ryan Thanks! It's called Combine Path in my version of Inkscape, but I combined, then broke them apart, and was able to make a difference of the resulting paths and get the result I'm looking for. If you write your comment as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Inkscape but its usually called Compound Path and [this official guide](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/advanced/tutorial-advanced.en.html) tells me it exists in Inkscape.

> Inkscape can Combine paths into a compound path (Ctrl+K) and Break Apart a compound path into separate paths (Shift+Ctrl+K). Try these commands on the above examples. Since an object can only have one fill and stroke, a new compound path gets the style of the first (lowest in z-order) object being combined.

I'd make the letter into an Outline which you say you've done. Then with it on top of the shape and both selected would try hitting <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I can explain what's going on.

I can draw a polygon, put a character on top, mark both in path mode (1) and convert to path (2) (after making a copy):

[image]

The copy is made to put the character again into the polygon, which fits exactly in my case. I prove this, by putting the character which is opaque to the bottom and with 3 red, opaque rectangles, the top one on top, the second is below the transparent polygon but above the yellow character, and the third is below both of them. 
I guess you experience like me an optical illusion, which makes the overlapping of yellow G and red bar look orange, but I assure you, it is pure red, which is visible in the second image, where I moved the bars to fit together - you see, it is one red color.

[image]

I guess I found the reason, why creating a differnce didn't work for you: Your shape has a border in the same color. Half of the border width goes into the polygon, half of its width goes to the outside. If you create the difference, the inner hole gets a border too, and the border is partly ranging into the hole. I made a very thick, green border, to show the effekt (the lower two objects). 
The green G is the shape of the hole in the polygon. The black character 'G', which is copied into the picture again and put below in z-order, only shines through through the transparent, green border. Only a very small part is not covered by the border and remains black.

If the character has a border too, it will cause a similar effect in the opposite direction. So the difference is too big or to small.

The conclusion is, that you may work in the way Ryan explained or with polygons and characters without border.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this exact problem.  The issue is, Inkscape ignores the stroke on text when doing the difference operation.  So, how do you deal with this?

1. Determine whether or not the stroke is large enough to completely obscure the actual primary font letter (the part that exists with or without the stroke).
2. If the stroke completely obscures the primary font letter entirely, then convert the stroke to a path, unselect everything, switch to the "edit path by nodes tool", select the text and the object, perform the difference operation.  The operation will leave behind the primary font letter, but the entire region obscured by the stroke will have been removed from the object.
3. If the stroke does NOT completely obscure the primary font letter, then you will simply perform the operation detailed above, plus the same operation again, but selecting the left over letter instead of the (now non-existent) stroke of the letter.

I know the above works because I literally just did this.